# How to add bottom line to multiple UITextField in subviews by swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to add bottom line to all of my textfield in my subview.

This is my code.

```
for view in self.detailView.subviews as! [UIView] {
        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            //                if textField.text == "" {
            //                    // show error
            //                    return
            //                }

            var border = CALayer()
            var width = CGFloat(1.0)
            border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

            border.borderWidth = width

            textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
            textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

            return
        }
    }
```

But it only add bottom line to the last textfield not all of it.
This is What i got

[image]

How can i fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can add imageView OR label (bg color is white) after your textfield, and fram should be CGRect(x: myTxtField.frame.origin.x, y: myTxtField.frame.origin.y + myTxtField.frame.size.height + 2, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added return keyword at end.

Try to loop whole view with its subviews like as

```
for view in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
            if let textField = view as? UITextField {
                var border = CALayer()
                var width = CGFloat(1.0)
                border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: width)

                border.borderWidth = width
                textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
                textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
                textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }
```

I have added one more  line of code `textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None` so that if the border style is different in design then it will change by programmatically.

Comment: Instead of traversing through subviews of a view, it would be better to make your custom UITextField class and implement the add border functionality inside it. That would be reusable.

Comment: I was redirected to this question from another post similar to this one, but since your answer had been accepted, i would prefer to answer the unanswered question. and that comment was  just about sharing one of the approach. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and easy method
Just put background image of textfield
This image have a white background and underline so you use transparent background instead white background

[image]